# Convert cURL request to Guzzle PHP

Tags: php, curl, guzzle, guzzle6

I am trying to convert existing cURL request to Guzzle 6. This is the cURL request. The code for curl request is like this.

```
$xml = file_get_content('new.xml');

// Initialize handle and set options
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL,     $this->xml_post_url );//
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $this->sslcert );//
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY,  $this->sslkey );//
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $raw_request );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: close') );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $this->sslcertpasswd );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD,  $this->sslkeypasswd );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true ); // capture the response to a string

// give it 3 tries
for ($i=1; $i<=3; ++$i) {

    $raw_response = curl_exec($ch);
    $response_HTTP_CODE = (int) curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );

    if (200 <= $response_HTTP_CODE and $response_HTTP_CODE < 400) {

        if ($raw_response !== false) {

            curl_close( $ch );
            return $raw_response;

        }

    }
    elseif (500 <= $response_HTTP_CODE and strlen( $raw_response ) > 0) {

        $offset = strpos( $raw_response, '<errortext>');

        if ($offset !== false) {

            curl_close( $ch );
            break;

        }
    }

    sleep( 1 ); // give it a moment
}

curl_close( $ch );
```

Is there anyway to convert this into Guzzle request in sane way with retry option as well if possible.

This is what I tried

```
$request = $this->getClient()->post($this->request['endPointUrl'], [
        'body' => $xml,
        'cert' => $this->request['sslCert'],
        'config' => [
            'curl' => [
                CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
            ]
        ]
    ]);
    $response = $request->send()->xml();
```

But I am getting cURL exception.

Comment: Show us your attempt at converting this to guzzle

Comment: Edit you question with the code, please don't put it in the comments

Comment: `But I am getting cURL exception.` - what exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright finally I resolved this issue. I am posting my solution with a hope that it might help someone.

```
$client = new Client();
$client->setDefaultOption('verify', false);

$response = $client->post($endPointUrl, [
                'body'    => ['file_filed' => $xml],
                'cookies' => true,
                'cert'    => [$sslCert, $sslCertPassword],
                'ssl_key' => [$sslKey, $sslKeyPassword]
            ]);

if (200 === $response->getStatusCode()) {

    $xmlResponse = $response->xml();

} else {

    // do something with error.

}
```

For retry I used [Guzzle retry subscriber](https://github.com/guzzle/retry-subscriber)